# Backbone.js Model.save() not working with https

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, https

We're working on a web app with Backbone.js/Marionette on the fronted and Django on the back. Everything worked properly but when we switched the webserver to https some requests broke down. Looking at it in detail, we saw that most of the requests work well except for one Model.save(). Our call looks like:

```
model.save(attributes, {
           patch: true,
           success: function (model, response, options) {...},
           error: function (model, response, options) {...},
           })
```

Following the documentation we saw that this method does two request:

- First a POST (if the model is new) or PATCH (if it is an update),
  that is well done via HTTP
- And a second GET request, we imagine it is for sync purposes.

It is the second request which is sent via http instead of https.

We don't know how to force this request to be via https. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is any such second GET request. Can you point to that part of documentation...? t's probably something from your code.

Comment: I've found the problem, i was using a third-party library called tasty pie which overrides Backbone.sync and does the second request, it is getting the response url header from the first post and for some reason that header is not set to https